# How do i check whether my list contains any symbols or numbers on python

Tags: python

I am making a code breaker game on python and need to make a if statement that checks whether the list contains any symbols or numbers.

So it would tell me that:

```
list=[hello, bonjour, 4 , hola]`
```

contains a number.  And:

```
list2=[hello, bonjour, hola]
```

does not contain a number

Comment: Just check if any element in list is not a letter

Comment: Please post some example lists, and maybe some code that you have tried.

Comment: Please read through [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and actually try to write something before posting a question.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
>>> test = 'abc123%def'
>>> any(not x.isalpha() for x in test)
True
>>> test2 = 'abc'
>>> any(not x.isalpha() for x in test2)
False
```